# Install GD on PHP 5.6

Tags: php, ubuntu-16.04

My web app is running on PHP 5.6.4 and Nginx on Ubuntu Ubuntu 16.04.1.

I am getting the following error in my browser:

```
FPDF error: GD extension is required for GIF support
```

I have recently reinstalled the server locally, so I am presuming GD library needs to be installed. So I ran the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-gd

sudo service php5.6-fpm restart

sudo service nginx restart
```

But I am still getting the same error message, can anyone advise what I should do please?

Comment: Did you check the `php.ini` and uncommment the `extension=` line?

Comment: Yes, the line now reads:  extension=php_gd2.dll

Comment: Does `phpinfo()` show it is installed? And btw ... `.dll` - isn't that a Windows library? IIRC extension on Linux have a `.so` extension

Comment: Did you ever get this issue resolved?  If so, please share.